# Posting to Database with explode array

Tags: jquery, sql, autocomplete

What i have is JQuery and AutoComplete. Everything works great until i try to post to SQL...

I have it pulling CityName, State Abbreviation, and Zipcode into the autocomplete here is the coding for that...

At the moment i have it displaying with a Space like so

> Springfield Mo 65803

but if the City Name has 2 words like so

> Des Moines IA 50301

it errors because of the separator... i could probably put the separator as a comma but wouldn't look good on site...

```
<?php
if (is_numeric($_REQUEST['term']))
{
$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'DBUser', 'DBpass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

$rs = mysql_query('select StateInitials, City, ZipCode from locations where ZipCode like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" GROUP BY StateInitials, City', $dblink);

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['City'] .' '. $row['StateInitials'] .' '. $row['ZipCode'],
            'value' => $row['City'] .' '. $row['StateInitials'] .' '. $row['ZipCode']
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
}
else
{
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;

$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'DBUser', 'DBpass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DBName") or die(mysql_error());

$rs = mysql_query('select StateInitials, City, min(ZipCode) AS "Lowest Zip" from locations where City like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" GROUP BY StateInitials, City', $dblink);

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['City'] .' '. $row['StateInitials'] .' '. $row['Lowest Zip'],
            'value' => $row['City'] .' '. $row['StateInitials'] .' '. $row['Lowest Zip']
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
}
?>
```

as you can see i have it autocompleting City Name  Or Zip

here is my coding to separate it and save as LocationID

```
    if(isset($_POST["OriginCombo"]))
        {
            $Origin  = $_POST["OriginCombo"];
                $pieces = explode(" ", $Origin);
                $OriginCity = $pieces[0];
                $OriginState = $pieces[1];
                $OriginZip = $pieces[2];


        $location_id = $this->Origin->GetLocationID($OriginState, $OriginCity, $OriginZip);
        if ($location_id == -1)
        {
            // error
            die("origin error");
        }
        else if (is_array($location_id))
            $location_id = $location_id[0];
        $this->Origin->LocationID = $location_id;

        }
```

Comment: you could use a regex to grab \s..\s\d+ then remove that from the original string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering zip at last make change as

```
//first step
                $zip = array_pop($pieces);
                $state = array_pop($pieces);

                //second step
                $city = implode(" ",$pieces);

                $OriginCity = $city
                $OriginState = $state;
                $OriginZip = $zip;
```

or better if you use string functions and similar logic to $_POST["OriginCombo"] value

*EDIT**

I tried this in a test like so and it displays Array for city

```
<?php
$_POST["DestCombo"] = "Des Moines ID 76789";

                    $Dest  = $_POST["DestCombo"];
                    $pieces = explode(" ", $Dest);              
                //  $DestCity = $pieces[0];
                //  $DestState = $pieces[1];
                //  $DestZip = $pieces[2];

                $zip = array_pop($pieces);
                $state = array_pop($pieces);

                //second step
                $city = implode(" ", $pieces);

                $DestCity = $city;
                $DestState = $state;
                $DestZip = $zip;

                echo $DestCity;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $DestState;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $DestZip;
                ?>
```

OUTPUT WAS:

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/SiteName/public_html/test.php on line 14

ID
76789

Comment: Wouldn't that still give me the same error i have now where the cityname is seperated

Comment: I did a test on that and the city displays     Array

Comment: it works .... just add semicolon after $OriginCity = $city; and use my code to test strings like "Des Moines IA 50301" or even "Des IA 50301"...

Comment: $city = explode(" ", $Dest); is wrong ..it should be $city = explode(" ", $pieces);

Comment: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/SiteName/public_html/test.php on line 14

ID
76789

Comment: sorry it should be $city = implode(" ",$pieces); as in my first reply

Comment: how about that thanks... i was just use to writing explode... typo thanks alot for the help